# Iterate over Mock returned value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, magicmock

I'm trying to Mock method that returns a list. After setting `return_value`, it still return a Mock object instead of list, so I can't iterate over that object.

Example of function that I want to test:

```
def func(db_engine):
    query = f"SELECT * FROM table"
    query_result = db_engine.execute(query).fetchall()
    extracted_val = []
    for res in query_result:
        extracted_val.append(res[1])
    return extracted_val
```

Example of test:

```
def test_fun():
    query = MagicMock()
    query_res = [("name_1", "value_1"), ("name_2", "value_2")]
    expected_vals = ["value_1", "value_2"]
    db_engine = MagicMock()
    db_engine.execute(query).fetchall().return_value = query_res
    vals = func(db_engine)
    assert expected_vals == vals
```

In summary, `db_engine.execute(query).fetchall()` must return list, so I can iterate over `query_result`, but it doesn't happens. Althou `query_result` has a correct values in atribute `return_value`, I can't iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to mock chained call doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#setting-return-values-and-attributes).  Here is the unit test solution:

`func.py`:

```py
def func(db_engine):
    query = f"SELECT * FROM table"
    query_result = db_engine.execute(query).fetchall()
    extracted_val = []
    for res in query_result:
        extracted_val.append(res[1])
    return extracted_val
```

`test_func.py`:

```py
import unittest
from func import func
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class TestFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        query_res = [("name_1", "value_1"), ("name_2", "value_2")]
        expected_vals = ["value_1", "value_2"]
        db_engine = MagicMock()
        execute = db_engine.execute.return_value
        execute.fetchall.return_value = query_res
        vals = func(db_engine)

        db_engine.execute.assert_called_with("SELECT * FROM table")
        execute.fetchall.assert_called_once()
        self.assertEqual(expected_vals, vals)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/61318070/func.py            7      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/61318070/test_func.py      16      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        23      0   100%
```

Python version: `Python 3.7.5`